# use geometry proximity to color a cube

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I would like to create a shader that mix colors in a cube based on the distance of diferent points to the mesh

Let's say we have a scene with a cube and 3 points

Now we would like to create a shader that would give a color texture to the cube depending on the distance from each of the points to the mesh of the cube.

I'm completly new to blender, and feeling a bit lost with so many nodes.
I just tried to set up the situation like this

Geometry nodes
[image: geometry nodes proximity]

Shading
[image: shading color defined by distance]

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to use geometry nodes for that. All you need shader nodes have:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just made the same system of nodes as in the image, and also getting some results but not so much influence to the cube as what your images shows ? I also tried using cycles and evee.

Could the same concept be applied for an environtment equirectangular texture ?
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264499/bake-depth-weighted-textures-using-mix-from-multiple-cameras